# Receive broadcast message from 255.255.255.255 in php

Tags: php, sockets, broadcast

I am using following code to broadcast message to 255.255.255.255. I want the client application to receive the message. What would be the receiver side code?

Also is it possible to check the code by running the server and client from the same computer or i must use 2 different computers to test them?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$port = 56721;

set_time_limit(0);

$broadcast_string = "test";
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("Could not  create socket\n");
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1);
while(true){
     socket_sendto($socket, $broadcast_string, strlen($broadcast_string), MSG_DONTROUTE, '255.255.255.255', $port);
}
socket_close($socket);
```